# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$'

Tags: php, exception

The PHP function below is producing this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$', on this line: `throw new ( '' . 'Illigal name for service name "' . $name . '" is given' );`

Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
function registerService($name, $provider) {
    if (strlen( $name ) < 1) {
        Exception;
        throw new ( '' . 'Illigal name for service name "' . $name . '" is given' );
    }

    $this->_Services[$name] = $provider;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Surely you just made up that code? (If not, please provide a reference to where such "valid" code was purported, because [here is a counter-case](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    Exception;
    throw new ( '' . 'Illigal name for service name "' . $name . '" is given' );
```

To this:

```
throw new Exception('Illegal name for service name "' .$name .'" is given' );
```

Also, normally you'd throw an Exception in a try catch block:

```
try {
    throw new Exception('Just testing');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
//Output: Caught exception: Just testing
```

Comment: exceptions are rarely thrown and get caught within the same function...

Comment: To build on comment by @KarolyHorvath  A more typical use case would be something like `try { registerService($name, $provider) } catch (Exception $e) { // do something with Exception }`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Of course. The OP is a beginner and I'm providing a very simple example like you would find at http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php In practice, no one would ever immediately throw an exception after entering into a try catch...

Comment: @ElliotB. They would if you told them to :)